# whether is $\sum_{k=0}^{j-1} \binom{i}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{j-2} \binom{i-1}{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{j-1} \binom{i-1}{k}$ true or false?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I have tested some trivial samples when $j = 1,2,3$. But I can't prove if it is true or false generally.
Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that 
$${i\choose k}={i-1\choose k}+{i-1\choose k-1}$$
, which can be proved by expanding the terms.

Comment: Or combinatorially: all groups of $k$ from $i$ either contain the max of the set (last term) or not (first term).